# SQL Oracle Join query and get all records from today

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query like this:

```
SELECT contact.PUBID,
  contact.LASTNAME,
  contact.FIRSTNAME,
  contact.MIDDLENAME,
  contact.CELLPHONE,
  doc.PUBID,
  doc.ISSUER,
  doc.ISSUEDATE,
  doc.SERIES,
  doc.DOCNUMBER
FROM CONTACT contact
INNER JOIN DOCUMENT doc
ON contact.PUBLICID = 'ab12'
WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

I want to get all records from today but have an error:

```
ORA-00920: wrong relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 143
```

Can you help me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE);

It is an incomplete **condition**. WHERE clause is used to filter the rows based on a condition.

```
WHERE table.column =  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Also, be aware of **datetime**. While you are using TRUNC on SYSDATE, it will truncate the **time portion**, however, if you have time portion in your date column, it will not match with **TRUNC(SYSDATE)**.

You would need to apply **TRUNC** on both sides.

```
WHERE TRUNC(table.column) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

But the above is not good from **performance point of view**. If you have a regular **B*Tree index** on the date column, it will be **ignored**, due to the **TRUNC** function.

It is better to use a **DATE RANGE CONDITION**:

```
WHERE date_column
BETWEEN 
        TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND     
        TRUNC(SYSDATE) +1
```

Answer (score 1):

In `WHERE` clause you must specify some CONDITION for filtering rows.

For example:

```
WHERE trunc(start_date) = trunc(SYSDATE)
```

Here start_date - column from your table, `DATE` data type.

So you need to decide, which column should be today.

By the way, your join condition a little bit strange too. You produce cartesian join. Are you sure this is what you want?...

Comment: "*WHERE trunc(start_date) = trunc(SYSDATE)*" will ignore the index on `start_date`. It is better use a date range condition to use the regular index scan. Else, use a function-based index. I prefer a date range.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I am not sure if author, who asks about `WHERE TRUNC(sysdate)` knows about indexes... But ok, you already put it in your answer

Comment: My point is, since you have suggested `TRUNC(start_date`, it is always good to mention the pros and cons.